# Normalize points in Python so that RMS distance from origin will be sqrt2

Tags: python, normalization, points, normalize

I want to implement the DLT algorithm and I have 6 object points (X,Y,Z,1).T and 6 image points (u,v,1).T , that are the projection of the object points to an image plane.

So before implementing the DLT I have to normalize data.

More specific I found that I have to do the following:
2D image points should be normalized so that their centroid is at the origin and their root-mean-square distance from the origin is sqrt(2)

Any idea how I can do that in python?

Answer (score 1):

Taking 6 image points for two images, one original and other warped, then:

```
x1 = np.array([202,202,500,523,530,522])
y1 = np.array([459,473,403,403,405,434])
x2 = np.array([283,285,526,544,552,550])
y2 = np.array([482,494,371,367,365,392])
img1 = np.column_stack((x1,y1))
img2= np.column_stack((x2,y2))`

def normalise(img):
    '''
    input:img = image points that we want to normalize
    return:Tr = Transformation that normalises the points
    normalised_points = Points normalise by Tr
    '''
    s = np.sqrt(2)/((1/25)*np.sum((np.sqrt(abs(img - np.mean(img,axis=0))**2))))
    m = np.mean(img,0)
    normalised_points = np.zeros((25,3))
    Tr = np.array([[s, 0, m[0]], [0, s, m[1]], [0, 0, 1]])
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        normalised_points[i][0] = s*img[i][0] + m[0]
        normalised_points[i][1] = s*img[i][1] + m[1]
        normalised_points[i][2] = 1
    return Tr, normalised_points

Tr1,normalised_X = normalise(img1)
```

[Ref](https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/courses-i-teach/ECE661.08/solution/hw4_s1.pdf)